# Bitwise AND/OR Operator is Appending?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm just playing with some bitwise operators to refresh myself on how they work. I found something really weird, but perhaps it is just a fundamental misunderstanding of how bitwise operators work.

This program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int base = 16;
    cout << (base << 2) << endl;
    cout << (base >> 2) << endl;
    cout << (base &  0b0001) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs this:

```
64
4
0
```

The first two I expected, but `0` for the last one seems a bit odd (no pun intended), as I had expected to see `1`. If I do `base | 0b0001` I get `17`. It seems like the bit pattern is being appended to the end. Is that what is supposed to happen, or I am missing something here?

I am using G++ v4.8.2.

Comment: No, nothing is being appended - `16 AND 1 == 0`, `16 OR 1 == 17`.

Comment: LOL Confusing C and C++ semantics-2.0

Comment: @wildplasser are you just saying that `16 and 1` is the same as `16 && 1`? I'm trying to find the name of the `and` operator in C++, but cannot remember... how are the "named" logical operators called?

Comment: @wildplasser, found them, digraph and trigraph operators :) (just digraph in the case of logical ones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `base` is `16`, i.e. `10000` in binary. Now AND it with `00001` and see what's happening.

`10000 & 00001 = 0` ->0 in any base

`10000 | 00001 = 10001` -> 17 in decimal

Comment: *facepalm* I really should have been testing with 15. That was the bit pattern I had in my head the whole time. Thanks, that was a silly mistake.

Comment: @OliverSpryn many many times I also thought that 1111 is 16 :)